# Smooth Concentric Radial Gradient in CSS

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics

I'm trying to create a blurry donut shape like this on a canvas with js.
I tried

```
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(128, 128, 128, .1)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)");
```

But I only get
[image]

It has a distinct defined circle at the stop radius. What I want is a smooth falloff. Something like this..

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're after a Gaussian blur rather than a gradient.
You can create such a blur using the `ctx.filter` property and pass in a CSS filter value `"blur(Npx)"`.
However Safari still doesn't support this property, so for this browser, we need to use a shadow as a workaround.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
if (ctx.filter === "none") {
  ctx.filter = "blur(60px)";
}
else { // Safari still doesn't support ctx.filter...
  ctx.shadowColor = "#34aaff";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 120; // x2
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 800;
  ctx.translate(-800, 0); // we draw the actual shape outside of the visible context
}
ctx.arc(400, 400, 200, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.lineWidth = 125;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#34aaff";
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas width=800 height=800></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add one or more color stops to control the shape:

```js
gradient.addColorStop(0, "White");
gradient.addColorStop(0.3, "rgba(128, 128, 256, .5)");
gradient.addColorStop(0.4, "rgba(128, 128, 256, .5)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "White");
```